# What is 'this' in this use of apply within this js implementation of memoize?

Tags: javascript, this, apply

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
  var cache = []; 
  return function(n){
    if(cache[n]){
        return cache[n];
    }
    cache[n] = func.apply(this,arguments);
    return cache[n];
  }
};
```

I'm just trying to understand why 'this' is used in func.apply here...What does it refer to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I think this is a great explanation of how "this" is bound. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Answer (score 1):

Your function `memoize` returns a new function which caches the results, if a function call with the same first parameter (e.g. `1`) has been made.

`function#apply` takes two arguments:

1. The current context (a.k.a. `this` in your function)
2. The array(-like) of arguments you would like to pass in.

`this` simply refers to the context that your function is called in. Passing it into `apply` simply ensures that your memoized function continues to work as one would expect from a regular JS function.

A few examples:

```
var a = function(number) {
    console.log(this);
}

var b = _.memoize(a);

a(1); // this refers to window
b(1); // this refers to window as well

a.call({ test: true }); // this refers to { test: true }
b.call({ test: true }); // this refers to { test: true } as well
```

If you were to pass `null` for example instead of `this` as the first argument of `func.apply`…

```
cache[n] = func.apply(null, arguments);
```

…it would not work anymore:

```
a(1); // this refers to window
b(1); // this refers to window as well

a.call({ test: true }); // this refers to { test: true }
b.call({ test: true }); // this refers to window
```

and in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), `this` would always be `null` for `b`.